require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
I got this errer messages when using require:
const ideasRouter = require('./routes/ideas'); ^ ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
I want to import router from './routes/ideas.mjs'; but not working. How to solve this problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
